# Proving a sequence converges with two given properties

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I found the following exercise in my calculus notes:

> Let $(x_n)$ be a real sequence such that $|x_n|\leq 2$ for all $n\geq 1$ and also satisfies the inequality $|x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}|<\frac{1}{8}|x^2_{n+1}-x^2_n|$ for all $n\geq 1$. Show that $(x_n)$ is convergent.

I've been stuck for a while in this problem. I tried to show that is a Cauchy sequence and therefore convergent, but I couldn't arrive to the desired result. Any help is welcome

Comment: Have you tried factoring the right-hand side and then using the hypothesis again? I think if you do this repeatedly, you can show the sequence is Cauchy and therefore convergent.

Answer (score 2):

From our assumptions we have
$$|x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}|<\dfrac{1}{8}|x_{n+1}^2-x_n^2|=\dfrac{1}{8}|x_{n+1}-x_{n}|\,|x_{n+1}+x_n|\leq\dfrac{1}{2}|x_{n+1}-x_n|$$
since $|x_n|\leq 2$ and $|x_{n+1}|\leq 2$. This should be useful in proving that $x_n$ is a Cauchy sequence. It should remind you of the proof of the Banach fixed point theorem if you're familiar with it.

Comment: Can I consider $m>n$ and use the inequalities you stated to arrive to some bound of $|x_n-x_m|$?